# What is the purpose of `--sync` with `xdotool mousemove` command?

Tags: mouse, xdotool

manpage of xdotool says

> --sync
>
> After sending the mouse move request, wait **until the mouse is
>   actually moved**. If no movement is necessary, we will not wait. This is
>   useful for **scripts that depend on actions being completed before
>   moving on.**
>
> Note: We wait until the mouse moves at all, not necessarily that it
>   actually reaches your intended destination. Some applications lock the
>   mouse cursor to certain regions of the screen, so waiting for any
>   movement is better in the general case than waiting for a specific
>   target.

I don't quite understand the purpose of `--sync` with `mousemove` command.

When a script "depends on actions being completed", does the script necessarily "actually move" the mouse, so that `mousemove` command can start to be executed?

Is there some easily understandable example?

Thanks.

Comment: I’m not quite sure what exactly your question is, but imagine a script that moves the mouse from one window to another and does some task with the second one for which it’s necessary that the mouse has moved to it. Naturally you want to actually perform the mouse movement before going on, hence wait for it. If this helps I’ll expand it to an answer.