# What are the differences between `key` and `type` commands of xdotool?

Tags: xdotool

[The `xdotool` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/xdotool.1.html) says:

> key: Type a given keystroke.

> type: Types as if you had typed it.

It is beyond my understanding. Could you explain how they differ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically `type` will type a string, `key` will type individual keys or key combos. For example here's two ways to type "Hello world!":

```
xdotool type "Hello world!"
xdotool key H e l l o space w o r l d exclam
```

---

More info from [`man xdotool`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xdotool.1.html) (trimmed down a bit):

```
key keystroke [keystroke ...]

    Type a given keystroke. Examples being "alt+r", "Control_L+J", "ctrl+alt+n",
    "BackSpace". Multiple keys are separated by '+'.

    Example: Send the keystroke "F2"
     xdotool key F2

    Example: Send 'a' with an accent over it (not on English keyboards, but 
    still works with xdotool)
     xdotool key Aacute

    Example: Send ctrl+l and then BackSpace as separate keystrokes:
     xdotool key ctrl+l BackSpace

type something to type

    Types as if you had typed it. Supports newlines and tabs (ASCII newline and 
    tab).

    Example: to type 'Hello world!' you would do:
     xdotool type 'Hello world!'
```

Comment: Thanks. I see. I also appreciate if you could consider my other related questions https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098762/does-xdotool-key-delay-pause-for-specified-delay-between-typing-every-two-co https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098726/what-is-the-purpose-of-sync-with-xdotool-mousemove-command https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098769/import-unable-to-read-x-window-image-resource-temporarily-unavailable