# "import: unable to read X window image: Resource temporarily unavailable"

Tags: lubuntu, xorg, screenshot, imagemagick, xdotool

On Lubuntu 18.04, I am trying to take a screenshot of the current focused window. I am using `import` from Imagick following https://stackoverflow.com/a/32165476.

It fails in a tab of lxterminal

```
$ import -window "$(xdotool getwindowfocus -f)" /tmp/file.png
import-im6.q16: unable to read X window image `31457284': Resource temporarily unavailable @ error/xwindow.c/XImportImage/4982.
import-im6.q16: missing an image filename `/tmp/file.png' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/1287.
```

it succeeds in a xterm window

```
$ import -window "$(xdotool getwindowfocus -f)" /tmp/file.png
$
```

Do you know why the problem happens? How can I solve the problem? Thanks.

[Someone has similar script](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=893506)

> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> echo "Enter the name of the window:"
> read window
> window_id=`xwininfo -name $window | awk '{print $4}' | grep -i 0x`
> import -window $window_id $window.jpg
> ```
>
> Like I said before, this doesn't work completely, but I thought I'd
>   post it anyway. I've gotten it to work for small programs like
>   Calculator, Dictionary, Atomix... nothing like Firefox, gedit, etc. .
>   If you try to do it for larger programs, you'll actually get an error
>   of the following sort:
>
> ```
> import: unable to read X window image `0x3200efb': Resource temporarily unavailable.
> ```
>
> I think this arises from the fact that these programs actually yield
>   multiple window IDs:
>
> ```
> dill@LAMP:~$ xwininfo -tree -root | grep gedit | awk '{print $1}'
> 0x3000071
> 0x3000003
> 0x3000001
> 0x300001e
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Kubuntu 18.04. I tried

```
$ sleep 5s && import -window "$(xdotool getwindowfocus -f)" ~/Desktop/file.png
import-im6.q16: unable to read X window image `83886084': Resource temporarily unavailable @ error/xwindow.c/XImportImage/4982.
import-im6.q16: missing an image filename `/home/dkb/Desktop/file.png' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/1287.
```

and

```
$ sleep 5s && import -window "$(xdotool getactivewindow)" ~/Desktop/file.png
$
```

The latter command which uses `xdotool getactivewindow` works in konsole (version 17.12.3) and in lxterminal (version 0.3.1).

`sleep` is to let me switch from the terminal to another application's window. The command catches active windows of Firefox and geany.

As for

> Do you know why the problem happens?

I don't really know but searching `man xdotool` for `windowfocus` tells us that

> Uses XSetInputFocus which may be ignored by some window managers or programs.

Whether that also applies to `getwindowfocus` isn't explicitly mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. removing `-f` from my command solve the problem on lxterminal. Not sure why.